# Power Automate Custom Connector - Token Invalid, Invalid Audience

Tags: azure-active-directory, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I have built a few custom connectors before but for some reason am having real issues getting a custom connector to authenticate against an api i have written.

The API is written in .netcore 5, hosted as a WebApp in the same tenant i am trying to connect from. I've checked the authentication setup and the ClientId is pointing to the 37008370 clientid guid in the below image.

This is how I am setting up the Auth in the connector
[image]

I've connected to this API using a blazor app so I think authentication is setup correctly.

When I try and setup the authentication for a custom connector though I get the following response

```
{  "content-length": "0",  "date": "Wed, 20 Oct 2021 10:11:51 GMT",  "request-context": appId=cid-v1:4e1e4b6a-ace8-48e9-8121-546d6e834953",  "www-authenticate": "Bearer error=\"invalid_token\", error_description=\"The audience 'api://37008370-*********' is invalid\"",  "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",  "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET"}
```

I think I have setup everything correctly and cant see where I am going wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: Have you tried giving clientId as Application Id Uri(from portal) i.e; clientId:api://3700xxx-xxx in your app settings.

Comment: Do you mean authenticate against the API directly? From the documentation I have read that's not the correct way to do it.

Comment: It does however work. What are the downsides of doing it this way?

Comment: I don't think there is any downside for theis way as far as i know.Infact in the backend depending on the version of token you are using, it adds api:// prefix in some cases .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audience of token should always match the client id of the app registered.The cause of the error is the same. Audience is api://xxxx-xx and client id=3700-xxx.
The resource can be an App ID GUID for the Resource, or a valid App ID URI which is registered on the Resource. AAD should be able to  identify which resource you are trying to reach based on the value you provide.

> Note that if you use an App ID GUID, you will get a token from AAD
> where the Audience claim is the App ID GUID. Alternatively, if you use
> an App ID URI, you will see that URI as the audience claim in the
> token.

So here you need to add `clientId :api://xxxxx-xxxx` (which is Application Id uri present in the expose an api blade of the azure ad app registration portal) in the app settings of the code .

"aud" value  generated for token by azure is also controlled by "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" property in AD application manifest.

This property defines a version of the access token that will be generated.
Check your jwt token in http://jwt.io If you get this .
Check the manifest of your azure ad .app"accessTokenAcceptedVersion" property value is probably null or one, or should be two . If it is null maybe adding api:// prefix is to be considered. else api:// prefix can be ignored.